# Hide the upload multiple file option in document library sharepoint 2010

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, hidden

How do i go about hiding the "Upload Multiple Files... " option in document library using jquery?..i do not have access to the sharepoint designer so only with content editor webpart i have to do it..anu suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this, assuming the link element has the value UploadMultipleLink in its ID:

```
$(function() {
  $("[id$='UploadMultipleLink']").css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: Hi Farrell, thanks for the reply - but i have noticed in the page source the id of the link is id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl01_ctl05_UploadMultipleLink" i dont want to use this since i have heard it is kind of dynamic..is there a work around for this?

Comment: The jQuery selector I used in the example is an "Select ID which ends with". So it selects all the **********UploadMultipleLink elements. In other words, it doesnt matter what is generated before UploadMultipleLink. It also passes on whateversharepointgeneratesUploadMultipleLink.